# Check Validation for Headers and Column Counts in .CSV File using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

Qn,

I have CSV file with 8 columns. Importing it in SQL table via SSIS . The file needs to fail if the columns of the csv file are more or less.

Qn,

Also is there a check for valid headers in the csv file. the testers have tested it with the data as header and out of 13 rows it reads 5 rows . I need to throw error if there is incorrect header as well.

Please advise...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**for your firSt question you can use following script in vb.net to check the number of columns in file with extension ".csv"**

```
If reader.EndOfStream Then
MessageBox.Show("The CSV file is empty, please update", _
            "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
Application.Exit()
End If

'Dim s As String = reader.ReadLine()
Dim lineContents() As String = Split(reader.ReadLine(), ",")
Dim NoOfCol As Integer

NoOfCol = lineContents.Length

IF not NoOfCol = 8
MessageBox.Show("Error")
End IF
```